# I failed to build Qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, building

I want to build Qt for my windows machine but it doesn't work.

I entered from a directory called Qt-5.8.0-build:

```
..\Qt-5.8.0-src\configure.bat -debug-and-release -platform win32-g++ -prefix C:\Qt\Qt-5.8.0-bin-x64
```

But I got some errors:

```
C:/Qt/Qt-5.8.0-src/qtbase/tools/configure/environment.cpp: In static member function 'static Compiler Environment::detectCompiler()':
C:/Qt/Qt-5.8.0-src/qtbase/tools/configure/environment.cpp:144:50: error: 'KEY_WOW64_32KEY' was not declared in this scope
                                                  KEY_WOW64_32KEY).toLower();
                                                  ^
C:/Qt/Qt-5.8.0-src/qtbase/tools/configure/environment.cpp: In static member function 'static QString Environment::execute(const QString&, int*)':
C:/Qt/Qt-5.8.0-src/qtbase/tools/configure/environment.cpp:389:60: error: '_popen' was not declared in this scope
     FILE *proc = _popen(command.toLatin1().constData(), "r");
                                                            ^
C:/Qt/Qt-5.8.0-src/qtbase/tools/configure/environment.cpp:399:29: error: '_pclose' was not declared in this scope
         int r = _pclose(proc);
                             ^
<builtin>: recipe for target 'environment.o' failed
mingw32-make: *** [environment.o] Error 1
```

What could I do to make it work?

Thanks for help

Comment: compiler should not  have -std=c++0x or -std=c++11 for that code to work, it's ISO spec functions and problem with mingw is that it defines `__STRICT_ANSI__` , which disables declarations of functions with underscore.

Comment: How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure you use proper spec? the win32-g++ is meant for mingw32, if you are using something else (mingw64 or some other gcc strain for windows) you need check documentation how to enable ISO compatibility

Comment: I believe it's mingw32. I got this from mingw.org

Comment: I enabled it but it doesn't work

Comment: Compiling Qt with MinGW is notoriously difficult. Usually it does not work without tweaking two or three things. First, the original mingw (from mingw.org) is pretty much dead this days. MinGW-w64 is the actively developed successor: Depending on which bitness you want to compile for use downloads in “Toolchain targetting Win64/32” from here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/ Then google (part of) the error message. Usually something useful crops up. Especially if the Qt version you’re trying to build has been released for a month or two.

Comment: It works now but there is an other problem. At the end of configure it checks the gold linker and then a window appears with the text: ld.gold.exe doesn't work anymore. My options are "Debug" and "Close program". When I use the second it continues with checking things. Then I type mingw32-make -j4 and then: it compiles but suddenly there are a lot of problems. The entry point "_ZdaPvy" was not found in the DLL ...\rcc.exe. It appears more than one time. After this there are ptoblems like "waiting for unfinished jobs" and then compiling was aborted